# Android execute method from within AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loading

I have created an activity that generates a UI with google maps and displays the user location, which begins as:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_display);

    Button myLocationBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myLocationBtn);
    Button searchRequest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchRequest);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            touched = false;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    });
    searchRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            onSearchRequested();
        }
    });
    initialiseMapView();
  }
```

This screen takes a while to load, which I figure is the result of actually calling and running map info and getting the user location, which is run within my method initialiseMapView();. So I have tried to introduce AsyncTask as follows:

```
private class loadMap extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        initialiseMapView();
        return null;
    }
}
```

All that I changed in my original code is that I changed initialiseMapView(); to new loadMap().execute();. The app crashes everytime I try to run this activity, I believe its because the initialiseMapView method is not within the loadMap class, but I'm not sure.

Please help :(

---

Here is the initialiseMapView method:

```
private void initialiseMapView() {

      mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
      mapController = mapView.getController();

      locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      mapView.setSatellite(false);

      GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(51.500152 * 1E6), (int)(-0.126236 * 1E6));
      mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

      mapController.setZoom(mapView.getZoomLevel());

      mapController.setZoom(14);

      mapFromQuery("london");

      mapView.invalidate();
  }
```

If this cannot be done is there some way I can display the screen while the content loads?

Comment: provide the initialiseMapView function definition ...... and log cat

Comment: just you can from background thread update your `UI`, you can't.

Comment: Is there any way I can display the screen while the content, such as the map, loads?

Comment: did you find out which of the function calls in initialiseMapView() "takes a while to load"?

Comment: no I haven't. I'm not sure what would be the best way to figure that out, and assumed it would be a good idea to have the whole process run in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

you can not call

> initialiseMapView();

inside doInBackground() method as it is running on a different thread than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any `work related to UI` in initialiseMapView as it is being called from doInBackground so please confirm the same............

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what others have said, your AsyncTask subclass should implement the following:

onPreExecute() executes on the UI thread before the background task starts.  This is probably the ideal place to initialize your mapview.

doInBackground() executes in the background and must NOT attempt to perform any UI functions. It's the ideal place to make your network calls and download your map data.

If you want to update your UI from the background task, make calls to publishProgress() which will cause onProgressUpdate() to be called in the UI thread.

Sample code:

```
  class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
      protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
      int count = urls.length;
      long totalSize = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
          totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
          publishProgress((int)((i/(float)count)*100));
      }
      return totalSize;
      }

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
      setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
      showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
      }
  }

  ...

  new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

ETA: A couple more things to consider. Whenever you have a thread running in the background, you have to consider the possibility that the foreground task could go away at any time. For example, if the user exits the app while the data is still loading, or if the user even rotates the device.

If your onProgressUpdate() method makes a reference to myMapView, consider that myMapView may no longer be a valid MapView object. (I assume the Android framework knows to ignore updates on View objects that are no longer relavent, otherwise apps would be failing everywhere.)

If your background task is cpu-intensive, you might consider calling cancel() (e.g. in onStop()) that tells the background task to abandon its work.  Or better yet, use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to pass a reference to your background thread across to the new instance of your app so that the background task can continue its job uninterrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding the method to the onPreExecute, but it didn't speed up the page load.

Comment: You're talking about speeding up the time it takes for the GPS to lock in, or the map data to arrive over the network?  There's probably nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I would just link to run the GPS stuff in the background and display the UI with a loading dialog. At the moment if I click 'search button' it takes about 8 seconds to display the UI because it is waiting for the map (and thats with Wifi on!). I just want the UI to come up quickly.

Comment: If the entire device is frozen during that 8 seconds, that sounds like you're doing some sort of networking or I/O in the UI thread. Otherwise, it sounds like you're updating the UI from the background thread and the updates are being ignore, or you're updating the UI from onPostExecute() instead of in onPreExecute().  That's my best guess anyway.

Comment: At the moment all of the UI, map data, http calls are all executed from within the main activity. I am trying to get the http calls and map generation to happen in the background so that the user doesn't have to wait for the UI to load with all the map stuff.